# Could somebody explain why the answer for this question is as shown? I don't get it.

Tags: normal-distribution

**Q:** Alice has routes for travelling to work. Travel times on these routes are normally
distributed.

- Route A takes on average 60 minutes with a standard deviation of 20 minutes.
- Route B takes on average 70 minutes with a standard deviation of 10 minutes.

**Work starts at precisely 9:00 and Alice does not want to be late.**

(ii) Which route should Alice take if leaving home at 7:30? Justify your answer.

**Ans:** Route B. To be late the trip must take 90 minutes. This is rare for both routes but is 1.5 sigma over the mean for Route A and 3 sigma greater than the mean for Route B, i.e. considerably rarer for Route B.

Like to be late, shouldn't the trip take > 90 mins and not 90 mins only? Also I don't get the 1.5 sigma over the mean for Route A part and the 3 sigma greater than the mean for the Route B part. How is that deduced? Like drawing a rough sketch of the graph, I though Route B would have a sigma of 2 instead of 3 greater than the mean...

Comment: The source is incorrect. It is supposed to say 2 sigma greater than the mean.

Comment: Ok, thank you. One more thing, how do you deduce Route B is rarer here? Like I don't get why a greater standard deviation would lead to a rarer option.

Answer (score 1):

As mathlander mentioned, 90 minutes is $1.5 \sigma$ and $2 \sigma$ above the means for Route A and B respectively.

You are right that "being late" corresponds to "trip taking $>90$ minutes." The probability of being late is therefore the area of the right tail of each normal curve on the interval $(90, \infty)$. You can show that the tail area on $(\mu + 1.5\sigma, \infty)$ is larger than the area on $(\mu + 2 \sigma, \infty)$.